# Which method in swift can be used to find the distance between the BLE devices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

i have implemented two methods for checking availability of the Bluetooth feature and to find the discoverable device around us. Now i would like to find the distance of the peripheral around us., for these feature which method can be used and what codes to be implemented. expecting a solution with an example code

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    println("\(__LINE__) \(__FUNCTION__)")
     println("checking state")

    if central.state != .PoweredOn {
        // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states correctly
                    return
    }
    central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil,options:nil)


}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!)
{

    var localname: NSString = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]! as NSString

    println("Discovered: \(peripheral.name)")

    peri = ["\(peripheral.name)"]



    if localname != " "
    {
        //centralManager!.stopScan()

        //self.peripheral = peripheral
        peripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)


    }


}
```

-thank you

Comment: You can read the `rssi` value as an approximation to distance but it isn't possible to translate this to an actual distance measurement

Comment: can i show the approximate distance in meter ?

Comment: It would be very approximate - probably +/- 5m or more

Comment: its ok. just i want to get an approximate distance. Which method can be used for that ? -thank you

Comment: You can call `readRSSI` on the `CBPeripheral` - this will invoke your `ripheralDidUpdateRSSI:error:` `CBPeripheral delegate` method

Comment: Excuse me., can you pleas make it clear. only i need to write readRSSI or i need to write any other method for that ?

Comment: You need a connection to the peripheral, which means that the peripheral must be running some sort of BLE service, then once you have a connection you can request the RSSI.

Comment: actually i have  not connected to the peripherals. for establishing a connection between the device which method want to be implemented -thank you

Comment: One more doubt can i list out the range or frequency of the device that are available around the device

Comment: hi @Paulw11. i have implemented methods for finding RSSI value device name and all. But i cant connect the device yet. Which method can be helpfull for connecting the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get  an approximate distance by read RSSI method. It will not return distance in any centimeter or metric values. You should convert it to a understandable format